# Different results for the same function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can someone clarify to me please why past2 is NOT negative when this code is run? Even though past is.

Thanks.

```
NSTimeInterval p1 = (arc4random()%600000);
NSTimeInterval past = -p1;
NSTimeInterval past2 = -(arc4random()%600000);
```

Comment: Search a definition for Random...

Comment: Can you clarify us why do you use `arc4random()`?

Comment: sorry, I meant something different. I edited the question now.

Comment: The is a completely different question compared to the original. You might want to post edits in a way that the history is clear. Particularly when answers have been obsoleted. In my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arc4random() returns an unsigned int (u_int32_t), so trying to make it negative is coercing the result to unsigned as well, which is why you're getting a very large positive number instead of a negative number.

If you want to get a negative random result in one call, try:

```
NSTimeInterval past2 = - (int) (arc4random()%600000);
```

joe